# how to fix this error? java.lang.arrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 0

Tags: java, string, int, system

hi i have this problem im doing a calculator where u introduce the weight of something idk an Orange or lemon and u put 1kg (introduce 1) then u put the price of it can be idk 5 usd (introduce 5) then i multiply it 1x5=5 then i tell to the client well with how much u will pay he said idk 10 usd so i introduce 10 and my calculator do 5-10=5 its there where i have the problem with my code that part of change of client (5 of 10bucks) repeats 2 times (ask me 2 times for the ammount of client for pay) i tried to put 0 (zero) in the line : vuelto= new float[1]; put gives me an error how can i fix it?

theres the code

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class arreglo1 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner ingreso = new Scanner(System.in);
        Scanner peso = new Scanner(System.in);
        Scanner precios = new Scanner(System.in);
        Scanner vuelto1 = new Scanner(System.in);

        float[] kilo; //definir un arreglo
        float[] precio;
        float[] vuelto;
        kilo = new float[2]; //iniciar un arreglo
        precio = new float[2];
        vuelto = new float[1];
        float Total;
        float Vuelto1;

        System.out.println("Ingrese el peso del Producto:");

        for (int i = 0; i < 2; i = i + 1) {

            kilo[i] = peso.nextFloat();

        }
        System.out.println("\nIngrese precio del Producto:");

        for (int j = 0; j < 2; j = j + 1) {
            precio[j] = precios.nextFloat();
        }

        //////Total A Pagar
        for (int i = 0; i < 2; i = i + 1) {
            Total = ((kilo[0] * precio[0]) + (kilo[1] * precio[1]));
            System.out.print("\nTotal a pagar: " + Total);

            //////Vuelto para el cliente

            System.out.println("\nIngrese monto con el que se va a pagar:");

            for (int b = 0; b == 0; b = b + 1) {
                vuelto[b] = vuelto1.nextFloat();
                Vuelto1 = (float)(Total - vuelto[b]) / -1;
                System.out.print("\nVuelto: " + Vuelto1);

            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: you have 4 scanners in your code. all of them do the exact same thing. i wonder why you have them...

Comment: for (int b = 0; b == 0; b = b + 1)  you just run it once?

Comment: yes just run one time is for pay the 2 products i bought

Comment: yes i see and i delete the scanners, thanks didnt notice it xD, but still dont know why give me an error i just want run the part of "vuelto" (change of money for the cllient) 1 time

Answer (score 0):

The last for loop (the "veulto" part) will be run twice because it is part of the body of the previous for loop (the "Total A Pagar" part). The entire body of the for loop is executed while `i<2`. 
A closing brace should be added to seperate the body of the first for loop and the second, if you only want "veulto" to be executed once.

```
for (int i = 0; i < 2; i = i + 1) {
            Total = ((kilo[0] * precio[0]) + (kilo[1] * precio[1]));
            System.out.print("\nTotal a pagar: " + Total);}
```

Obviously the last closing brace should also be deleted to balance them out:-)

Solving the problem actually reveals another one, though, as the local variable Total may not be initialised, which javac enforces. The solution is to initialise it to some value when it is declared, probably to 0.

```
float Total = 0.0f;
```

While you're at it, the "veulto" part doesn't need to be in a for loop, it's only executed once.

Answer (score 0):

Why do you need this part of code?

```
for (int b = 0; b == 0; b = b + 1) {
   vuelto[b] = vuelto1.nextFloat();
   Vuelto1 = (float)(Total - vuelto[b]) / -1;
   System.out.print("\nVuelto: " + Vuelto1);
}
```

I guess, you want to read a price from customer only once, so it's enough
to write

```
Vuelto1 = Math.abs((float)(Total - vuelto1.nextFloat()))
System.out.print("\nVuelto: " + Vuelto1);
```

**Note:** Math.abs() returns absolute value of number so you get always a positive number.